# Adjust the amount of jitter for a Plotly strip plot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Is there a way to adjust the amount of jitter for a plotly strip plot? That is, the equivolent of the `jitter` parameter in [seaborn.stripplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html). I could not find anything from the [plotly strip documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.strip.html). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jitter is enabled for graph updates, although it cannot be specified directly in plotly.express. 1.0 is the maximum value. Jitter is enabled from the reference [example](https://plotly.com/python/strip-charts/#strip-charts-with-plotly-express).

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.strip(df, x="total_bill", y="day",)

fig.update_traces(jitter=1.0)
fig.show()
```

[image]